# What will be the context for CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-connectivitymanager

What will be the context for CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE in a Fragment? I have checked getActivity also but it is giving an error.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            Log.d("ConStatus", "Data Connection On");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d("ConStatus", "Data Connection off");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.i("ConStatus", "No Active Connection");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace, when you're using getActivity?

Comment: I wrote getSystemService(getActivity().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); And there it self it gives an error please create a method getSystemService.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getSystemService()` is a method on `Context`. A `Fragment` would call it using `getActivity()`:

```
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Im using barsherlock Fragements but it crashing . giving me Nullpointer exception in my case

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when trying to implement a Google map offline tile provider within a fragment (based on 0ne_Up's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938723/google-maps-offline-mode-on-android-application?rq=1)). I solved it by using the following:

```
private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
...
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().
    getSystemService( getActivity().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
```